# select option without ng-option in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select>
    <option>active</option>
    <option>Deactive</option>
</select>

$scope.isActive = $scope.data.gameStatus;
```

My option is not dynamic so I think shouldn't use `ng-option`, how to use selected the `active` option, assuming the value of $scope.isActive is `true`.

Comment: You need to tie a model to the select and set values to whatever you want to represent activate or deactivate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your `select` with `ngModel`

Try like this

```
<select ng-model="mycontrol.value">
     <option>active</option>
     <option>Deactive</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
$scope.mycontrol={
    value:''
};
$scope.mycontrol.value="active";
```

**EDIT**

the data coming from the api is true, not 'active',

try like this

```
var flag = true;
$scope.mycontrol.value= flag  ? "active" : "Deactive";
```

Comment: I got  Cannot set property 'value' of undefined but my mycontrol is defined.

Comment: @SivaNatalie declare before assign value which i mentioned in my answer

Comment: can I ignore the .value? can't do it without .value? btw, the data coming from the api is true, not 'active', but I have to set the active to be the selected.

Comment: @SivaNatalie nope you have to declare model name with contain `.` in the name. whatever. I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks mate! appreciate your effort and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for `ngSelected` [here](https://d3k3c6k76sjl6h.cloudfront.net/StoreSync.png).

Just add `ng-selected="isActive"` on your `<option>`.

Comment: This wouldn't change the value of isActive if the option was changed however

Comment: The OP doesn't ask to do that. The OP just asks how to set the 'active' option as selected when `isActive` is true.

Comment: @SixteenStudio does that mean when I want to save ng-selected is no good in my case?

Comment: If you expect the user to change the select, e.g. change from "active" to "deactive", then ng-selected is no good for saving, as you have said. As I mentioned in my post, it might make sense to use a checkbox in this situation? Let me know if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a little tricky problem. First of all you need to set `ngModel` directive. But even if you do so it will not work anyway, because your model is of Boolean type while option value is of course a String. Angular will not bind such model properly. (Of course, only if you don't want to use `ngOptions` and want to go with simple static options, which totally makes sense in this case).

Luckily, official documentation contains [some hints](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#binding-select-to-a-non-string-value-via-ngmodel-parsing-formatting). The solution is to add one more helper directive to convert boolean to string for option selection and string to boolean for writing model value from selected option.

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.isActive = true;
})
.directive('convertToBoolean', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
                return val == 'true';
            });
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
                return val + '';
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainController">
    <select ng-model="isActive" convert-to-boolean>
        <option value="true">Active</option>
        <option value="false">Deactive</option>
    </select> {{isActive}}
</div>
```

So yea, using ngOptions would be simpler in this case :)

Comment: that's why sometime I rather use jquery.. $('.class').prop('checked',true);

Comment: It's actually the best solution if you don't want to use ngOptions. The solution you accepted will likely have problems because when you change selection you model will become string, not a boolean. So make sure to convert it back if it's important.